# Full Calendar Stay on Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I am attempting to implement a calendar via Full Calendar. I am able to do everything I need, except I am trying to load a JQuery dialog after a user clicks on an event. I know that returning false in the "eventclick" section will make it stay on the page, but adding any sort of function seems to negate doing this. I need to be able to load the dialog without it taking me to the Google Calendar page. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar-2.0.2/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='fullcalendar-2.0.2/lib/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-2.0.2/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-2.0.2/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-2.0.2/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-2.0.2/gcal.js'></script>

<div id='calendar' style="width:75%;height:75%"></div>

<script>


$(document).ready(function() {



    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/myFeed',

            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {     
        var temp= loadDialog(calEvent.description,calEvent.location,calEvent.title);
        return false;
        }

    });
});
</script>


<script>

$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });


  });

function loadDialog(description,location,title)
{

$("#className").val(title);
$("#location").val(location);
$("#description").val(description);
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
}
return false;
</script>


<div id="dialog" title="Class Information">
    <h2 id="className"></h2></br>
    <h1 id="location"></h1></br>
  <div id="description"></div>
</div>

</html>
```

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the event is still linked. Even if your code worked, the `href` is taking you to another page. So, get rid of the link. Here is how I do it:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/myFeed',
    eventRender: function (calEvent, element) {
        element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
        element.attr('onclick', 'loadDialog("' + calEvent.description + '","' + calEvent.location + '","' + calEvent.title + '");');
    }
});
```

You'll also need to change those `.val(` in your `loadDialog` to `.html(`. `val` is for form elements.